# Post request in javascript with Java rest api doesn't work

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, post, xmlhttprequest

I have a dynamic web project and I want to send data on a mysql database on a remote server. 
So, I have a REST api with this code in the file `libraryPersistentBean.java` :

```
public void addDemande(DemandeInscription demande) {
        Connection con = null;
          String url = "jdbc:mysql://my-ip:3306/my-database-name?useSSL=false";
          String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

          String userName = "my-username";
          String password = "my-password";
         // List<DemandeInscription> demandes = new ArrayList<DemandeInscription>();
          try {

             Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
             con = DriverManager.getConnection(url , userName, password);

             PreparedStatement st = 
             con.prepareStatement("insert into demandeInscription(name, city, address, food, type, email) values( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
             st.setString(1,demande.getName());
             st.setString(2,demande.getCity());
             st.setString(3,demande.getAddress());
             st.setString(4,demande.getFood());
             st.setString(5,demande.getType());
             st.setString(6,demande.getEmail());


          //   int result = st.executeUpdate();                

          } catch (SQLException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
          } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
          }    

    }
```

I call this function here :

```
    @POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void post(@FormParam("name") String name, @FormParam("city") String city, @FormParam("address") String address, @FormParam("food") String food,
        @FormParam("type") String type, @FormParam("email") String email) throws IOException {

    DemandeInscription demande = new DemandeInscription(name, city, address, food, type, email);
    LibraryPersistentBean libraryPersistentBean = new LibraryPersistentBean();
    libraryPersistentBean.addDemande(demande);



}
```

And my javascript file, I have :

```
function sendInscription(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var food = document.getElementById("food").value;
    var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'rest/demandes');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.send('name=' + name + '&city=' + city + '&address=' + address + '&food=' + food + '&type=' + type + '&email=' + email);

}
```

So, I don't have errors, but after a test, I have nothing in the database.
Do you have an idea why it doesn't work ?

Comment: I don't think your code ever reaches the post method. You should specify the full URL path in xhr.open.

Comment: Debug and check what you are getting when request came to server.

Comment: I already tried with the full URL and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I don't know how to use the debug mode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough points to comment but at first glance the `st.executeUpdate()` command is commented out. You also might need to do a `conn.commit();`. And lastly, you'll need a `conn.close();` at the end of the `addDemande` method so you don't leak connections. Preferably the `conn.close();` should be in a `finally` clause. Hope this helps point you in the right direction.

**Update:**

So here's your addDemande(...) method with the changes to commit and properly close the connections.

```
 public void addDemande(DemandeInscription demande) {
    Connection conn = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://my-ip:3306/my-database-name?useSSL=false";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    String userName = "my-username";
    String password = "my-password";
    // List<DemandeInscription> demandes = new ArrayList<DemandeInscription>();
    try {

        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

        PreparedStatement st = conn
                .prepareStatement("insert into demandeInscription(name, city, address, food, type, email) values( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        st.setString(1, demande.getName());
        st.setString(2, demande.getCity());
        st.setString(3, demande.getAddress());
        st.setString(4, demande.getFood());
        st.setString(5, demande.getType());
        st.setString(6, demande.getEmail());

        // Turn off auto-commit 
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        // Uncommented this statement that actually does the update
        int result = st.executeUpdate();

        // Commit the change
        conn.commit();

        // Release the resource
        st.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me where I need to put these functions (commit, close, executeUpdate) please

Comment: Yes, it works. It was necessary to uncomment the line `st.executeUpdate()`. Thanks !